# AWS Cloudfront + .NET User Controls = no _doPostback rendered - custom .browser file help needed

Tags: asp.net, browser, amazon-cloudfront, dopostback

We currently use AWS Cloudfront w/ our DNN 7.1 site but are having a problem with modules that use controls that require __doPostBack.

Normally our main site doesn't use controls like that but we're doing a revamp and want to add some new features that do require it. But, __doPostBack is never rendered when accessed via CloudFront. What we've done for now is created a page on one of our sub-domains which is not on CloudFront and setup an IFrame to display it which works but is less than ideal for various reasons.

Upon examination it seems like this is due to Cloudfront stripping the user agent and replacing it with 'Amazon CloudFront'.

I tried creating a custom .browser file which seems to be recognized but the Request.Browser call still says "Unknown". Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong with this .browser file?  I know it still needs the capabilities added in but the "browser" setting should be enough to at least make the call to Request.Browser show the provided name of "Amazon CloudFront" instead of "Unknown", shouldn't it?

```
    <browsers>
        <browser id="AmazonCloudFront" parentID="default">
            <identification>
                <userAgent match="Amazon CloudFront" />
            </identification>
            <capture>     
            </capture>
            <capabilities>
                <capability name="browser" value="Amazon CloudFront" /> 
            </capabilities>
        </browser>
    </browsers>
```

---

**UPDATE #1:**  I also tried adding the following to the system.web section in the web.config and then invalidated the site's pages in Cloudfront but no change.

```
    <clientTarget>
        <add alias="uplevel" userAgent="Amazon CloudFront" />
        <add alias="uplevel" userAgent="amazoncloudfront" />
    </clientTarget>
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**  I also tried adding the following to the Default.aspx file but this also did not appear to have any effect.  And yes, I have autoeventwireup set to true.

```
        <script runat="server">
            protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // Set client target to specify browser capabilities equivalent to Internet Explorer 6.0 and higher.
                Page.ClientTarget = "uplevel";
            }
        </script>
```

---

**UPDATE #3:**  I tried the following but still no __doPostback being rendered.

```
    <browsers>
     <browser refID="Default">
      <capabilities><!-- To avoid wrong detections of e.g. IE10 -->
       <capability name="cookies" value="true" />
       <capability name="ecmascriptversion" value="3.0" />
      </capabilities>
     </browser>
    </browsers>
```

---

**UPDATE #4:**  I am trying the following as a shotgun approach and put in all of the most recent unique capabilities from the other browser files.  This also produced no changes.

```
    <browsers>
        <browser refID="Default">
            <capabilities>
                <capability name="cookies" value="true" />
                <capability name="w3cdomversion"                   value="1.0" />
                <capability name="javascript"                      value="true" />
                <capability name="ecmascriptversion" value="3.0" />
                <capability name="javascriptversion"               value="1.8" />
                <capability name="layoutEngine"                    value="Gecko" />
                <capability name="supportsAccesskeyAttribute"      value="true" />
                <capability name="javaapplets"                     value="true" />
                <capability name="supportsDivNoWrap"               value="false" />
                <capability name="tagwriter"                       value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
                <capability name="frames"                          value="true" />
                <capability name="javaapplets"                     value="true" />
                <capability name="supportsCallback"                value="true" />
                <capability name="supportsFileUpload"              value="true" />
                <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
                <capability name="supportsMultilineTextBoxDisplay" value="true" />
                <capability name="supportsXmlHttp"                 value="true" />
                <capability name="tables"                          value="true" />
                <capability name="isColor"              value="true" />
                <capability name="screenBitDepth"       value="8" />
                <capability name="jscriptversion" value="6.0" />
                <capability name="vbscript"             value="true" />
                <capability name="supportsVCard"        value="true" />
                <capability name="maximumRenderedPageSize"         value="300000" />
                <capability name="supportsFontName"                value="true" />
                <capability name="supportsFontSize"                value="true" />
                <capability name="supportsImageSubmit"             value="true" />
                <capability name="supportsItalic"                  value="true" />
                <capability name="supportsBold"                    value="true" />
                <capability name="supportsCss"                     value="true" />
                <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
            </capabilities>
        </browser>
    </browsers>
```

Comment: Hi CodeConqueror,

I came across the same problem with a .Net solution that uses postbacks. I've opened a forum thread on the AWS site to see what Amazon think:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=503534#503534

I'm actually loathe to mock 'Amazon CloudFront' as a browser, presumably .Net is giving us some goodness by tailoring it's JavaScript to certain browsers. If we even the responses to a certain browser's capabilities other browsers might start failing? I'd need to read up about browser capabilities more carefully to find out for sure.

Gog

Comment: Yeah, I agree, it's not the path I WANT to take, but so far it's the only path I can see that might have some light at the end of it.

The only other thing I can think to do is to be able to exclude a specific page from being part of CloudFront but I haven't found a way of doing that.

I'll keep an eye on your post over there and see if anything comes of it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to see if setting the clientTarget value on the page to "uplevel" works ?

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Set client target to specify browser capabilities equivalent to Internet Explorer 6.0 and higher.
    Page.ClientTarget = "uplevel";
}
```

Comment: I'm trying it now.  I don't have the option of putting it into the code behind file since it's a DotNetNuke site (I'd need the source code, then recompile it and maintain those changes as DNN updates).  BUT, I looked into that setting and see that I can do it via the System.Web section of the web.config file.  I'm trying it out now and will report back after testing.

This is a setting I've never used before and didn't even know what it did, so thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Unfortunately, no dice.  It made no difference.  See Update #1 in my original post.

Comment: Also, as a test, I tried adding your suggested code to the default.aspx file in a script block but it didn't seem to have an effect.  See Update #2 in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - it looks like a similar issue with doPostback and an unknown user-agent was discovered when IE10 was released a few months ago.

To fix this and any future problem with an unknown user-agent Alexandre Alapetite created a browser file definition that looked like this

```
<browsers>
 <browser refID="Default">
  <capabilities><!-- To avoid wrong detections of e.g. IE10 -->
   <capability name="cookies" value="true" />
   <capability name="ecmascriptversion" value="3.0" />
  </capabilities>
 </browser>
</browsers>
```

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/662275/asp-net-user-agent-sniffing-and-ie10-internet-explorer-10

See if that works for you

Comment: I'm worried about this though, if you tell .Net that everyone is a certain browser e.g. IE10 then what will happen to all the other browsers (IE < 10, Webkit browsers etc)?

The browser capabilities feature must be trying to make sure all browsers work, if you work around that detection you may have issues in other browsers?

Comment: As it stands it's using default so even if it impersonated IE, it can't be any worse than it is right now (which is completely non-functional).

I'll try the browser file changes and report back later today.

Comment: No luck with this browser file.  I am attempting a modification of it for Ss and Gs.  See updates 3 and 4 in my OP.

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance this is still presenting an issue to those using ASP.NET Web Controls (more specifically __doPostBack) with CloudFront:

CloudFront will allow you to pass the original request (including the User-Agent) through to the origin, on a per-Behavior basis. Obviously this rules out caching, but should mean that your pages function as desired.

To do this, edit the relevant Behavior and for the Headers setting, select 'All'. You'll notice the option to set a TTL disappears.

Using the Headers setting, It's also possible to whitelist certain headers - so you can specify varying by the User-Agent value only. Again, given the variety of User-Agent strings, this is likely to limit the effectiveness of the cache for that particular Behavior.